# Organize ASP MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP MVC.

Im trying to build a website with a header, footer, menu and a place to the main content.

What is the best approach for that?
Partial views, areas?

Thanks

Comment: You might be better off going through some tutorials or sample for this. Check on MSDN and "your favorite search engine". As it stands your question is too vague.

Answer (score 3):

Use layout.chtml file, This will work as Master page to your site and will be available for all your views.

For MVC3 you may see: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

> **What are Layouts?** 
>   You typically want to maintain a consistent look and feel across all of the pages within your web-site/application. 
>   ASP.NET 2.0 introduced the concept of “master pages” which helps
>   enable this when using .aspx based pages or templates.  Razor also
>   supports this concept with a feature called “layouts” – **which allow
>   you to define a common site template**, and then inherit its look and
>   feel across all the views/pages on your site.

Answer (score 3):

You can use partial views for Header and Footer. For most of my Asp.Net MVC Projects, I use partial Views in master page. You can add your menu in the header partial view.

```
<body>   
<div class="contentdiv">
<% Html.RenderPartial("Header"); %>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="container containerbg" >
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
<% Html.RenderPartial("Footer"); %>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptsSection" runat="server" />
</div> 
</body>
```